# Terraform set azure storage account virtual network

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-network

How to set Azure storage account to allow access from specific subnet?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [azurerm_storage_account_network_rules](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_account_network_rules):

> Manages network rules inside of a Azure Storage Account.